# Не стандартный, горизонтальный скролл

Tags: javascript

Знает ли кто-то библиотеку, по которой можно сделать, скролл по типу http://iphone.hohli.com/#docs/gallery.html, только горизонтальный. Главное что-бы он был как на смартфонах, что-бы прокручивать, можно нажимать не только на сам скролл, но и элемент

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам такая "плюшка" нужна, как имитация эффекта, но на обычных устройствах. В общем, если не найдете каких-то готовых решений, то я [набросал вам пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/KsLgf/2/) того, как это можно реализовать. Пример очень сырой, но принцип, я так думаю, что уловим. Если пригодится, то плиззз.

Comment: большое спасибо, именно это я и хотел)

Comment: @Deonis а на чистом JS сможешь сделать?

Comment: @Camaz - а это что, грязный что-ли?

Comment: ну без jQuery  то есть

Comment: @Camaz, теоретически можно, НО представьте себе тот объем работы, который надо выполнить! В примере я использовал плагин jQuery [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), значит надо, грубо говоря, переписать его ручками, плюс не забывайте про ядро. В общем, для того, чтоб сделать это на нативном JS, мне бы пришлось забить на свою работу и с головой окунуться в изобретении велосипеда.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), поддерживает как вертикальные так и горизонтальные скроллбары, + судя по информации на сайте, работает на мобильных устройствах.